# Perf doesn't show build-id of the application itself

Tags: perf

When I run the following perf command for collecting user data

```
$ perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u -a -o perf.data.user ./test
```

The output of build-id checking is

```
$ perf buildid-list -f -i perf.data.user
dbd41c586ea6789f3b998ed28be6ff37134e917a /lib/modules/4.19.125/build/vmlinux
b5381a457906d279073822a5ceb24c4bfef94ddb /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
ce17e023542265fc11d9bc8f534bb4f070493d30 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
5d7b6259552275a3c17bd4c3fd05f5a6bf40caa5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
55a35b6df1526bf3d69586896785bf1df0bb4be6 [vdso]
59081d88e819c2fd3bcd8e58bc0c858c0ee2c3a9 /home/mahmood/bin/perf
8edd43fbf5a6d895172d205a7248a814e3b07bb2 /home/mahmood/kernel-4.19.125/test/test
2c0a469e1700fdd0b2f670737dabafeb9c38f909 /opt/glibc-2.23-install/libc.so
```

As you can see the `/home/mahmood/kernel-4.19.125/test/test` which is the binary has a build-id. That is fine. However, when I run

```
$ perf record -e cycles:k -j any,k -a -o perf.data.kernel ./test
```

I don't see the application's build-id in the same output

```
$ perf buildid-list -f -i perf.data.kernel
dbd41c586ea6789f3b998ed28be6ff37134e917a /lib/modules/4.19.125/build/vmlinux
49b4a1a69bb9aebaca5147b9821e1a3a2ca759f3 /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko
bb4e88298fe274b1bec7ba8ab24e6a9670b93d04 /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.ko
ee37b9e0cc9b7be3ca543ecfeaa6bde28b77df7d /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_nat.ko
2bc71fd8d0c750aa3427a31639ce75a16a3c288c /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko
e5dfa4829fe8f9ed3185b708225a5bab8d6d0afe /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_defrag_ipv4.ko
5d52d35a5b99dd81fed002ba571a7afe32b26cbd /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko
d19830cb5c697cb2583d327c28aa3961c945005d /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau.ko
b816c95c09032342acd644128cf4d21251b3578a /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb.ko
da3d32f0230efe8329fae49f9de60ddaeddf48a9 /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/drivers/ata/libahci.ko
b5381a457906d279073822a5ceb24c4bfef94ddb /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
55a35b6df1526bf3d69586896785bf1df0bb4be6 [vdso]
```

Is there any reason for that? I ask that because my analyzer checks the build-ids and gives me an error regarding the missing `8edd43fbf5a6d895172d205a7248a814e3b07bb2` which is my application itself. The analyzer has no problem with the former scenario.

UPDATE:

I think since I am profiling kernel activity, there is no sign of the program itself in the recorded data. However, if I run `perf record -e cycles -j any -a -o perf.data.kernel ./test`, then I also see program's build-id in addition to the the kernel files.

```
dbd41c586ea6789f3b998ed28be6ff37134e917a /lib/modules/4.19.125/build/vmlinux
49b4a1a69bb9aebaca5147b9821e1a3a2ca759f3 /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko
bb4e88298fe274b1bec7ba8ab24e6a9670b93d04 /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.ko
ee37b9e0cc9b7be3ca543ecfeaa6bde28b77df7d /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_nat.ko
2bc71fd8d0c750aa3427a31639ce75a16a3c288c /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko
e5dfa4829fe8f9ed3185b708225a5bab8d6d0afe /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_defrag_ipv4.ko
5d52d35a5b99dd81fed002ba571a7afe32b26cbd /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko
d19830cb5c697cb2583d327c28aa3961c945005d /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau.ko
b816c95c09032342acd644128cf4d21251b3578a /lib/modules/4.19.125/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb.ko
55a35b6df1526bf3d69586896785bf1df0bb4be6 [vdso]
59081d88e819c2fd3bcd8e58bc0c858c0ee2c3a9 /home/mahmood/bin/perf
8edd43fbf5a6d895172d205a7248a814e3b07bb2 /home/mahmood/kernel-4.19.125/test/test
b592b0baf11cf7172f25d71f5f69de2d762897cb /opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so
2c0a469e1700fdd0b2f670737dabafeb9c38f909 /opt/glibc-2.23-install/libc.so
```

Not sure though if I am right. Any comment is welcome.

Comment: I was going to say, if there are no samples in the program itself, it makes sense that a `perf.data` file only has info about paths hit by samples.  Maybe it would be a nice feature to also record something about the main executable for a record based on a single process / executable instead of system-wide, though.

Comment: Excuse me I didn't get the point. Can you explain more?

Comment: The program is a simple for and struct that writes somethings on a file and display. So, there should be some kernel activity for the disk and display. Isn't true? However, I see network related files. Although I am using ssh to run the program (printf on terminal), that make me confusing. I don't see any disk related files.

Comment: Also, in the user profiling, I see libphtread, but for the kernel, I don't see that. I can not think for any reason about that.